# Whats the last digit in css class col-md-x for? Where x is an integer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Example. We have col-md-4, but we can also have col-md-1 all the way until 12. 
What exactly does the number represent?

Comment: Read bootstrap basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It specifies the auto-layout columns when using bootstrap. Please see the documentation at [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: So basically, the screen is div'd up into 12 units, and your cols can sum up to 12 in a single row. Correct?

Comment: Almost, you first specify a div row, then div column, much like a spreadsheet

Comment: Don't forget to accept as answer if this answers your question.

Comment: So many downvotes. How are we supposed to learn when u get slammed for  asking.

Comment: Some people here forget, that there are beginners on this platform. Just keep asking your questions and try improving your questions by looking at how other questions get asked.

Comment: Thank you. I will.

Comment: @VishavPremlall you got so many downvotes because your question is simply off-topic and doesn't show any effort. If you did a small research and read the bootstrap documentation you will find the answer to your question. It's not against you but StackOverflow is no a Forum, we try to keep a high quality of questions/answer and there is some rules to respesct in order to ask/answer